# django-rest-framework- accepting id for submitted foreign key field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have the following models:

```py
class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Child(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

with serializer:

```py
class ChildSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Child
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'parent',)
        read_only_fields = ('id',)
```

and ModelViewSet:

```py
class ChildViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ChildSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = Child.objects.all()
    paginator = None
```

If I query the api, I get a json structure that looks like:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Child Name",
  "parent": 3
}
```

Which is exactly what I want.  However, if I try to PUT the same data back, I get the error:
`ValueError: Cannot assign "3": "Child.parent" must be a "Parent" instance.`

How can I make a submission like this work?  I should be able to submit my data in the same way I receive it from the API.

Comment: Probably looking for this: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`:

Example from DRF Docs:

```
class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ['album_name', 'artist', 'tracks']
```

Your code would most likely be:

```
class ChildSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    parent = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Child
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'parent',)
        read_only_fields = ('id',)
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  I needed to refactor your code to:
`parent = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Parent.objects.all())` as otherwise I got an error `AssertionError: Relational field must provide a 'queryset' argument, override 'get_queryset', or set read_only='True'.` and once I did set a queryset, I am back to the same issue as before: `ValueError: Cannot assign "3": "Child.parent" must be a "Parent" instance.`

Comment: Doh!  It was actually in a mixin from a third party package causing the issue.